# UILabel with some effects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, quartz-graphics

Can anyone help me how could I achieve an effect like this image [sample image](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/6249/sampleo.png) on a UILabel.

As you can see there some like a stroke/bevel effect on the label.
I got this image from a clock app so it means that its not a static image.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: With regards to your edit, when I said drawing bitmaps the image is still static, its just that you change it periodically -- so in this case, every second, ten seconds, minute, ten minutes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very likely not a label. It is most probably drawing bitmaps. That is, where you create an image with all your letters, numbers and punctuation looking like you want it to look, and you render portions of that image where you want them to write words, draw numbers, etc.

The other option you have, if it's a repeating pattern, is to create a very small image (a couple pixels high (as in 2) if you want interlaced look like in that image) and use `UIColor` to create a colour based on a pattern image, and set the font's colour in the label. That might work, I have not tested doing things that way. The look will be flat however, not bevelled going this route.

Comment: You can also create a custom font.